# If exist in mysql db don't submit the form

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, prestashop

I have a form in php where i have to check if `productid` and period is there in db if yes then don't submit the form.

write now I am checking

```
(if ($_POST[prodID'] == [productID'] && $_POST['Period']==['period'])
```

But how can i make select disabled or maybe the form will not get submitted if the above check is true?

Answer (score 1):

You have a bracket mistake in your code, correct that

```
(if ($_POST[prodID'] == [productID'] && $_POST['Period']==['period'])
```

to

```
 if ($_POST['prodID'] == ['productID'] && $_POST['Period']==['period'])
```

rest you want something like this

```
 $submit_button = "";
 if ($_POST['prodID'] == ['productID'] && $_POST['Period']==['period']) 
 {
    $submit_button = "disabled";
 }

 <input type="submit" <?php echo $submit_button ?> >
```

this will disable your submit button and stop form from submit also , you can write a message inside your if condition so that user will know why the form is disabled

Comment: also you can use the same code to hide the button just create a class hidden and pass it inside class when button is created :)

Comment: actully i am using prestashop i am havin problems with incloding this <?php echo $submit_button ?>

Comment: then modify the code as per smarty code standards it will work understand the flow and try to apply the code at the right place